# Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a project in asp.net mvc structure.I want to create the detail page of the books I bought from a web service, but I encountered a problem and could not solve it. I need help.

Web Api: https://gutendex.com/

These are the codes for my homepage.

```
@model BookListModel

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var books in Model.results)
        {

            <div class="col-md-3 text-truncate">
                <img src="@books.formats.imagejpeg" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">@books.title</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary stretched-link" asp-controller="Book" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@books.id">Details</a>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

```
public class BookRepository
    {
        private static List<Result> results;
        public static Result GetBooksById(int id)
        {
            return results.FirstOrDefault(b => b.id == id); // PROBLEM HERE 
        }
    }
```

```
 public IActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View(BookRepository.GetBooksById(id));
        }
```

```
@model Result

<div class="card mb-3">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img src="@Model.formats.imagejpeg" class="card-img">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">

                <h5 class="card-title">@Model.title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">@Model.subjects</p>
                <p class="card-text">
                    <small class="text-muted">3 days ago</small>
                </p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wrote a book repository class to help me, the id of the book comes from there with the help of a button, but my method returns a null value.

[It gives an error here, it returns null.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMPjg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your `private static List<Result> results;` is null. You should initialized that at some point/somewhere. Or load data into it, whatever is your intent. At least that is what the errors indicates, `FirstOrDefault` is an extensions method called on the collection, but that fails if said collection is null. And your code does not show if it is initialized somewhere.

i.e.

```
results = new List<Result> { new Result(...) }
```